# DKIM - many subdomains without multiple txt records

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, unix, dkim, opendkim

I've been having trouble with opendkim, figuring out how to best create records for multiple subdomains.

I've tried using wildcards to cover all of the subdomains and wasn't able to get it working. I settled on using a single key for all of my subdomains, but it doesn't seem to be working properly.

`/etc/opendkim/SigningTable`

```
*@new1.example.com new1._domainkey.new1.example.com
*@new2.example.com new1._domainkey.new1.example.com
```

`/etc/opendkim/KeyTable`:

```
new1._domainkey.example.com new1.example.com:new1:/etc/opendkim/keys/new1.example.com/new1.example.com.private
new1._domainkey.example.com new2.example.com:new1:/etc/opendkim/keys/new1.example.com/new1.example.com.private
```

I was hoping to have this working for all subdomains, without having to create a new text record for each of them. The above seems to work for the new1.example.com domain only where I get:

```
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do above, use a single text record for multiple subdomains, or do I actually have to create a txt record for each of them?